# WordPress prevent add_rewrite_rule redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

On a WordPress website I want content from

http://thesite.com/cars to display the content in http://thesite.com/cars/index

I am trying to do this with the following rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
  'cars/?$',
  'index.php?page_type=cars&name=index',
  'top');
```

It works except that it redirects to http://thesite.com/cars/index

Is there any way to prevent the redirect from happening?

Comment: do you want to display content from one page to another page ?

Comment: Yes basically, i added a post type called cars, the default page for /cars/ is the archive page but it's not possible to edit the content there in the same way in the admin panel.

Comment: I have not found a way to do the mod rewrite but I found out about the `has_archive` flag that I had set to `true`. With this set to false I can create a page with a slug of `cars` and achieve the same result.